# Take a taxi or catch a taxi?

Tags: idioms, expressions

- Catch a taxi
- Take a taxi
- Catch a bus
- Take a bus

What is the difference between these phrases in meaning?
Are they all correct?

Comment: The OED has this definition of catch in this sense "To be in time for and board (a train, bus, plane, etc.). Also more generally: to use (a train, taxi, etc.) as a means of transport; to take." - so, in effect "catch" and "take" could be considered synonyms in this particular context. You could use all of them. [see google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catch+a+taxi%2C+take+a+taxi%2C+catch+a+bus%2C+take+a+bus&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. [“catch, v., sense V.40.c”, July 2023](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/catch_v?tab=meaning_and_use#1262197550)

Comment: In New York City at least, "catch" is more likely with scheduled transportation as mentioned by @BillyKerr.  You'd sooner "grab" a cab than "catch" one.  "Take" is more about the trip than hailing or entering the vehicle.  You're also more likely to take _the_ bus to your destination than _a_ bus, where _the bus_ denotes bus service generally.  There are probably contexts in which one of these would be incorrect and the other not, but I can't think of them offhand.  Did someone suggest that a particular use of one of these phrases was wrong?  If so, can you give the context?

Comment: @phoog - Sheena Easton's 'baby' took the morning train, as I recall, but I guess that had more to do with scansion, or her (and the writer) being Scottish?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey perhaps.  "Took" is not totally out of place for a New Yorker; I used "more likely" and "sooner" for a reason.  But for example in response to the question "how do you get to work," the answer "I take the train" is probably the most natural.  The thing that strikes me as most attributable to poetic license is the inclusion of "morning."  (When I said "catch" is more likely with scheduled transportation, I meant more likely than  with unscheduled transportation, not more likely than "take" with scheduled transportation.  Ambiguity, ambiguity.)

Comment: In the UK, too, you 'catch' a mode of transport that follows a timetable (or 'miss' it if you are too late!).

Comment: I'm a native New Yorker, and I don't see anything wrong with "catch a taxi"; if anything it strikes me as slightly more natural than "grab a taxi"  *Catch a ____* does somewhat imply that there was some speed or effort involved.

Comment: Both are correct and almost completely interchangeable in both American and British English.   "Catch a cab" is more common use than "Catch a taxi" in American English, and in British English it's more likely to hear "get a taxi" than "take a taxi".

Comment: ...or **hail** a taxi.

Comment: @phoog - for me, as a Br. Eng speaker, "catch" doesn't necessarily imply scheduled transport, although that usage is also possible.  There could be regional differences at play here. For me, catching a taxi could be used to imply standing on a street, and getting on the next available taxi that passes by.

Comment: @phoog "took" is fine in NYC. I lived there for 15 years. And boy, was I glad to leave.

Comment: @Lambie I've lived in New York for far longer than 15 years, and for me at least "take a taxi" means "use 'taxi' as the mode of transportation for a journey" whereas "grab" or "catch" means "hail" -- to attract the driver's attention when the taxi is available.  In other words, those terms refer only to the beginning of the trip.

Comment: Yeah, well, there is also Why don't we grab lunch? OR Let me grab a sandwich and we'll leave. // How did you get here? I caught a cab. That does not mean hailed one. It means I took one. Anyway, the NY thing is just not relevant as people in all major cities in the US use the same lingo. So fuhgeddaboudit. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20a%20taxi%2Ctake%20a%20taxi%2Ccatch%20a%20taxi%2Cget%20a%20cab%2Ctake%20a%20cab%2Ccatch%20a%20cab&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for taxis and cabs...

[image]

...showing that we're 5-10 times more likely to ***take*** one than ***catch*** it (I've only included ***get** a taxi/cab* in the chart because it's more common than ***catch***). But [when it comes to ***buses***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20a%20bus%2Ctake%20a%20busi%2Ccatch%20a%20bus&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), we're much more likely to catch them than take them...

[image]

I think the reason for this is simply that we normally *catch* things that are *moving* and/or operate according to a scheduled timetable. In "movieland", the stereotypical catching of a cab in New York's super-busy Broadway involves stepping out into the street and hailing it down, but things don't usually work like that in the UK (or in real life in the US<sup>1</sup>, for all I know! :) I can see that *hailing* a cab leans towards *catching* it, but most UK taxis sit with all the others in a ***taxi rank,*** waiting for customers. And obviously taxis don't run to a timetable.

---

<sup>1</sup> When creating chart #1, I included ***cab*** because I thought ***taxi*** was more [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20a%20taxi%2Ctake%20a%20taxi%2Ccatch%20a%20taxi%2Cget%20a%20cab%2Ctake%20a%20cab%2Ccatch%20a%20cab&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3), and ***cab*** was more [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20a%20taxi%2Ctake%20a%20taxi%2Ccatch%20a%20taxi%2Cget%20a%20cab%2Ctake%20a%20cab%2Ccatch%20a%20cab&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3). But as the links in my preceding sentence show, there's little difference between the "combined" chart as actually shown, and the two corpus-specific charts.

Comment: Or in the UK, taxis are booked or ordered (by phone or app), when you might talk of taking them but definitely not catching them.

Comment: & of course you have to pre-arrange a private hire, you can't flag one down in the street.

Comment: You can't compare their usage if they don't mean the same. Apples and oranges.

Comment: @Astralbee: I don't understand. What are the apples and oranges here? The fact that I included ***cab*** as well as ***taxi***, even though the OP only asked about the latter? That makes no difference to the point I'm making, obviously. Sometimes I get the feeling people are just downvoting because it's *me.*

Comment: Sorry, but your answer misses the point of the question entirely. Catching and taking are different things. You can catch a bus *and then take it into town*. I really think we need to crack down on using ngrams to 'prove' answers are right. They can lend support to answers about frequency of usage and that's all. As for the downvote - I rarely downvote wrong answers unless I think it is likely to mislead. It's not personal and if you can strip back your answer so it just focuses on the differences between the two words I will gladly reverse it.

Comment: @Astralbee: But I *did* point out that the primary difference is *we normally catch things that are moving and/or operate according to a scheduled timetable*. Which taxis don't. That's by far the biggest factor so far as I'm concerned.

Comment: So called "street hails" are less of a movie thing and more of a New York City thing.  I've lived in three large US cities, one West Coast, one Midwest, one East Coast, and I've never seen this happen, except when I've visited New York, where it seems quite common (at least pre-ride-hailing apps).  There is, or was, a common misconception that street hailing is illegal where I live; not true, but probably says something about how uncommon the practice is.

Comment: @Juhasz: For all practical purposes, I'd say the OP's actual question was fully covered by Billy Kerr's initial comment: *"catch" and "take" could be considered synonyms in this particular context. You could use all of them.* Obviously at the margins one could say that ***catch** a cab* is closer to ***hail** a cab* than ***take** a cab*.  But would even a learner need to have that pointed out? They'd certainly need to be careful about making sure they understand *why* that is. (You'd raise a few eyebrows if you talked about hailing a ***train*** instead of taking or catching it! :)

Comment: Agreed.  Apologies for being unclear; I wasn't suggesting that we include *hail* in the discussion.  I only meant to comment on "things don't usually work like that in... real life in the US, for all I know!"  I was merely pointing out that in real-life-non-NYC-USA, things also tend not to work like that.  We non-New-Yorkers tend not to hail cabs on the street, and so we (or at least I) find *catch a cab* unnatural.

Comment: @Juhasz: oic. Well, as it happens, half-an-hour after I wrote my answer, I asked my housemate (who's spent a lot more time in the US than me) whether they might still flag down a cab outside a busy theatre on Broadway or similar (where in the UK the authorities would be more likely to insist on a taxi rank). Contrary to what you just said, my housemate said they *do* call moving taxis over like that, but you're the native, so I'll believe you. But for *most* people (UK and US), ***catch** a cab* is a bit "odd" because cabs don't run to a scheduled timetable, as pointed out by others besides me

Answer (score 0):

This depends somewhat on local variations in usage, but in general all of those should be perfectly acceptable and they don't really mean different things.

Sometimes 'catch a bus' implies you need to hurry because there's a schedule you're trying to work within, but it just as often does not mean that.

Answer (score 0):

'Catch' is the moment that you board the vehicle. For example, if you fail to catch a bus, you miss it.

'Taking' a vehicle refers to the whole journey on that vehicle. For example, you might say "*I took a bus part of the way, then walked the rest*".

So they are different - it's just that in many contexts you could say either and the overall meaning wouldn't change.

It's a bit unusual to say "catch a taxi", because taxis aren't scheduled. We'd normally say 'hail' or 'get' to refer to calling a taxi.

Answer (score 0):

To "take" a vehicle is simple, and it means to ride somewhere in/on it. It applies to all types of vehicle, whether you're a passenger or controlling the vehicle yourself.

We use "catch" for the same function, but it only applies to *a passenger*, like someone in a taxi, a bus, a friend's car or bicycle, and even your own private jet if you're not the pilot.

"Catch" also has other meanings, like to *get on board* a vehicle that runs on a schedule, or to *overtake* a vehicle, but those meanings doesn't contrast with "take", so might not be what you're asking.